# Inflated children of custom LinearLayout don't show when overriding onMeasure

Tags: android, custom-controls

I'm trying to show a `MyCustomLinearLayout` which extends `LinearLayout`. I'm inflating the `MyCustomLinearLayout` with the `android:layout_height="match_parent"` attribute. 
What I want is to show an `ImageView` in this `MyCustomLinearLayout`. The height of this `ImageView` should be `match_parent`, and the width should be equal to the height. I'm trying to accomplish this by overriding the `onMeasure()` method. What happens, is that `MyCustomLinearLayout` does become square like it should, but the `ImageView` is not showing.

Below my used code. *Please note that this is an extremely simplified version of my problem. The `ImageView` will be replaced by a more complex component.*

```
public MyCustomLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_myimageview, this);

    setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(height, height);
}
```

The `view_myimageview.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_myimageview_imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</merge>
```

So when I override the `onMeasure()` method, the `ImageView` is not showing, when I don't override the `onMeasure()` method, the `ImageView` shows, but way too small, because the `MyCustomLinearLayout`'s width is too small.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not how you override the `onMeasure` method especially of a default SDK layout. Right now with your code you just made the `MyCustomLinearLayout` square assigning it a certain value. But, you didn't measured its children so they are sizeless and don't appear on the screen.

I'm not sure this would work but try this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = getMeasuredHeight();
    super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
}
```

Of course this will basically do the work of `onMeasure` twice but the `ImageView` should be now visible filling it's parent. There are other solutions but your question is a bit scarce on details.

Comment: Had the same problem, tried your answer with only the second onMeasure and it works as well. Maybe the first one can be removed..