# TextView not appearing when programatically adding it to a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Basically as the title says. I have a class that extends `LinearLayout` and I want that LinearLayout to have a child `TextView` inside. The problem is, the TextView does not seem to appear.

Here is what I have so far, what exactly am I doing wrong?

**Update**: I Changed my code as following as you guys have suggested, and my `TextView` still does not appear....

```
public class CalendarCourseView extends LinearLayout {

    private int height;
    private int topMargin;
    private Course course;

    public CalendarCourseView(Context context, Course course, int topMargin,
                              int height) {
        super(context);
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        this.topMargin = (int) TypedValue
                .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, topMargin, displayMetrics);
        this.height = (int) TypedValue
                .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, height, displayMetrics);
        this.course = course;
        this.setBackgroundColor(course.getColor());
        setTextView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec), this.height);
        ((MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams()).topMargin = topMargin;
    }

    private void setTextView() {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this.getContext());
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup
                .LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setText(course.getName());
        this.addView(textView);
    }

}
```

**Update:** I pinned-point the problem. It is with onMeasure. I believe the TextView is not placed in the same position as the LinearLayout after height and topMargin change.

**Update:** Fixed it simply by changing calling super.onMeasure on onMeasure.

```
 @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, this.height);
        ((MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams()).topMargin = topMargin;
    }
```

I believe it is because `setMeasuredDimension(int, int)` only changes the dimension of the View and not the children. I would also have had to override `onLayout`. Calling the `super.onMeasure` also changes the children and simplified things.

Comment: I believe this is already answered by @Luksprog here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394181/inflated-children-of-custom-linearlayout-dont-show-when-overriding-onmeasure

Comment: `onMeasure` usually gets called more than once. Adding stuff there to the layout is usually a _bad_ idea. And you should use `MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec)` and not just pass in `widthMeasureSpec`, because it is not a size by itself.

Comment: @FlorentSpahiu I'm still unsure how does that affect the TextView not appearing? The LinearLayout is inflated just fine...

Comment: @DavidMedenjak where do you suggest I add the TextView then?

Comment: Either in the constructor or in `onFinishInflate` (which only works if inflating it from xml), or add some check to prevent it from being added again

Comment: Can you post the XML for the `MyView` class, and also post the code for the `ResponsiveTextView`?

Answer (score 2):

Check your code to see if

> course.getName()

has a value. Just for testing purposes, you can say

> textView.setText("MyCourseName");

for example.

This example below is working correctly for me.

```
public class CustomView extends LinearLayout {

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Log.d("CusotmView", "on constructor after super(context)");

        TextView textView = new TextView(this.getContext());
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup
                .LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setText("MyText");
        this.addView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Log.d("CustomView", "onMeasure");
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. This does indeed work, and helped me find that the bug was with the positioning of the TextView.

Comment: If it solved your problem, mark is as correct answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As it's been mentioned, calling `setTextView` from the `onMeasure` method is a bad idea. `onMeasure` is not always called consistentyly, like `onCreate` or `onStart`. On top of that, I don't think that you are properly adding the textView to the main view. I would put the `setTextView` inside the constructor like so:

```
public MyView(Context context, Course course, int topMargin,
                              int height) {
        super(context);
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        this.topMargin = (int) TypedValue
                .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, topMargin, displayMetrics);
        this.height = (int) TypedValue
                .applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, height, displayMetrics);
        this.course = course;
        super.setBackgroundColor(course.getColor());
        this.setTextView();
    }
```

I will also add that you aren't adding the `TextView` to the correct view. You are adding it to the `super` class, rather than the view that has been created. You are going to need to get a reference to the view you are trying to add the layout to. Maybe it would look something like this:

```
private void setTextView() {
        TextView textView = new ResponsiveTextView(super.getContext());
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup
                .LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setText(course.getName());
        //You should reference the object being created rather than the super class
        this.addView(textView);

    }
```

Comment: If you post the XML, like I asked earlier, it would be more helpful. :)

Comment: There is no associated xml, I'm using it as a custom LinearLayout. @BlackHatSamurai

Comment: Yep, I tried hard-coded string on setText as well and didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the class where you create the `MyView` object?

Comment: I simply call the constructor and add it to a view. Please see updated post

Comment: Can you post the XML for the file where you are initializing the views? Where you have the days?